# If $0 \neq x \in {_R}M$, then $Rx$ is a factor of $_RR$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm trying to understand the proof of Anderson-Fuller's Corollary 15.21 which states:

If $R$ is an artinian ring and $M \in R-Mod$, then
$$Soc(M)\trianglelefteq M \text{ (is essential in $M$}) $$

For this, he takes $0 \neq x \in M$, and states that $Rx$ is a factor of $R$, and knowing that $_RR$ is artinian and every factor of an artinian module is artinian, $Rx$ is artinian and $$\:Soc(Rx)= Rx \cap Soc(M) \neq 0$$ giving the essentiality of $Soc(M)$.

My question is on the beginning: If $x \in M$, why is $Rx$ a factor of $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $R\to Rx$ given by $a\mapsto ax$ is a surjective homomorphism of $R$-modules.

Comment: mmm... ok, so if I understand correctly, $Rx \cong R/ann^l_R(x)$, the left annihilators of x?

Comment: @LuisVera Right.